# Angular: How do I read a text file located in the assets folder?

Tags: angular, file, text

I am trying to open a .txt file which is in my assets folder. The name is "Maze1.txt". I am sort of new to these things so I was wondering if someone can help me read the text from this file. Thank you so much. If there is any more information needed, please tell me. :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the HttpClient for this (import and inject it as `httpClient`).

```
this.httpClient.get('assets/Maze1.txt', {responseType: 'text'})
        .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: I tried that, but I keep getting this error even after declaring http:               Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: has you import the HttpClientModule from '@angular/common/http' in your module and HttpClient in your service/component  from '@angular/common/http'. ? see  the doc: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: This is what I added in my app module: import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; and I also put it in the imports array. For my component, I added this on top: import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';                                                            It still does not work

Comment: I also added import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind. I found a working solution by using a constructor. For anyone looking for code that works, use this:

```
private httpClient: HttpClient;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient = http;
  }
```

and in the function: I used this:

```
this.httpClient.get('assets/Maze1.txt', { responseType: 'text' })
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Timon answer implied you injected HttpClient in the constructor, so might be better to just ask him to edit his answer. 
Also, a better way to inject HttpClient would be to delete the httpClient variable you declared, that is delete the line `private httpClient: HttpClient;` and change the constructor to `constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}`.