# I am looking for a way to show markup document texts from a file in asset folder in html as a pop-up in Angular

Tags: angular, assets

Text File Data ->

```
<b>Test</b>
```

Here is the angular html snippet i tried.
Code

```
<embed src=".\assets\docs\about\BRANCH_MASTER.txt">-->
        
        <object data=".\assets\docs\about\BRANCH_MASTER.txt">
          Not supported
        </object>
```

Output

```
<b>Test</b>
```

Problem is markup tags not serializing. It is showing as it is.
Is there any way to access asset file content. And Show them in html?

Comment: Here you have the answer on how to read it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523640/angular-how-do-i-read-a-text-file-located-in-the-assets-folder) and then u just put it in your modal.

Comment: This method worked . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do two things

First, retrieve data from the file. Use `HttpClient` to make an HTTP GET request to retrieve the content of the file test.txt. The `responseType` is set to 'text' to ensure that the response is treated as plain text.

```
  content = "";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('assets/test.txt', {responseType: 'text'})
      .subscribe((data) => this.content = data);
  }
```

Second, bind the data to a variable and use [innerHTML](https://www.cloudhadoop.com/angular-html-binding/) to display it in the template.This will render the contents of the file as HTML within the  element.

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```